# How to print the following pattern by using while-loops in python?

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, nested-loops

How can I print the following pattern using while loops in python?

`! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! !
\ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / 
\ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / 
\ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! ! ! ! ! / / / / / / / / 
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ ! ! / / / / / / / / / /`

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ExcCount = 22
SlashCount = 2

i = 1
while i <= 6:

    String = (SlashCount * "\ ") + (ExcCount * "! ") + (SlashCount * "/ ")
    print(String)

    ExcCount -= 4
    SlashCount -= 2
    i += 1
```

Comment: Your code does not seem to print anything and goes in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Ritiek Soz, forgot to increment `i`

Answer (score 0):

This may also be solved using `for` loop but since the question explicitly mentioned `while` loop:

```
total = 22
n = 0

while n < 6:
    side = n*2 
    middle = total - side*2
    line = '\\'*side + '!'*middle + '/'*side
    print(line)
    n += 1
```

Let me know if anything needs explanation.

Answer (score 0):

there are two easy ways to do this

```
while True:
    print '! '*22
    print '\ '*2+'! '*18+'/ '*2
    print '\ '*4+'! '*14+'/ '*4
    print '\ '*6+'! '*10+'/ '*6
    print '\ '*8+'! '*6+'/ '*8
    print '\ '*10+'! '*2+'/ '*10
    break
```

or maybe

```
x=0
while x<6:
    print '\ '*(2*x)+'! '*(22-(4*x))+'/ '*(2*x)
    x+=1
```